# How do I Calculate Variance with Missing Values coded as -99?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to calculate individuals' variances on multiple measures, however, if they skip a question it is coded as -99. I would like my formula to calculate the variance for these measures while ignoring/skipping/omitting the -99 values.

I am using excel to manage a reward system. If people meet certain criteria (finish the survey, do not randomly respond, answer % of questions), they receive compensation for their time. So, I do not want to change all of the -99 values to 0 or blank because it is a an indicator of how many questions they saw but chose to skip in a survey with lots of branching. If I wanted to get rid of them I would just use ctrl+f and replace them with "". Any suggestions other than using SPSS or other statistical softwares?

Currently my formula is: 
=IF(ISERROR(VAR(DJ4:EH4)),"",VAR(DJ4:EH4))

But, it could be simplified to =VAR(DJ4:EH4) to figure out how to do this.

I would like it to be something like: calculate the var(DJ4:EH4) except for cells = -99.

I tried =Var(DJ4:EH4, <"-99"), but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A first crack would be

```
=VAR(IF(DJ4:EH4=-99, "", DJ4:EH4))
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this,
to make it an array formula.

If your data contain any blanks, the `IF(…,"", …)` causes them to be processed as zeroes,
so revise that to

```
=VAR(IF((DJ4:EH4=-99)+(DJ4:EH4=""), "", DJ4:EH4))
```

using `+` to combine two Booleans in the sense of “or”
(because `OR(…)` doesn’t work in array formulas).

---

It had occurred to me that
it might be better to use `#N/A` instead of `""` for the cells you want to ignore,
but it turns out that this doesn’t work – the `VAR(…)` evaluates to `#N/A`.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Enter the following formula, but instead of pressing only `Enter`, press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` as this is an array formula.

```
=VAR(IF(DJ4:EH4<>-99,DJ4:EH4))
```